# How can I perform additional object configuration via parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm writing unit tests where the SUT (system under test) can undertake a wide variety of different configurations. Instead of adding a parameter for each combination, I decided to (or attempt) take an alternative, cleaner approach. For those that don't know, the `Fixture` object is from a library called AutoFixture, which handles seeding random test values.

Here is my failing test -

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var locate = Build(x => x.With(xx => xx.TicketNo, 123));

        Assert.AreEqual(123, locate.TicketNo);
    }

    private Locate Build(Action<ICustomizationComposer<Locate>> customizationAction)
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var customizationComposer = fixture.Build<Locate>();
        customizationAction(customizationComposer);
        var postProcessComposer = customizationComposer
            .Without(x => x.Attachments)
            .Without(x => x.Comments)
            .Without(x => x.Reviews)
            .Without(x => x.ScheduledCrew)
            .Without(x => x.PendingDecision)
            .Without(x => x.FinalDecision)
            .Without(x => x.ConflictResolution);

        return postProcessComposer.Create();
    }
```

As you can, I'm attempting to use the `Build` method to create a `Locate` object with a set of ignore rules via the `Without` method calls. This is the baseline object I require for each test. Each test has the option to ignore additional fields or hard code field values via the `With` method call.

I would expect to pass because I set my `Build` lambda parameter to set the `TicketNo` property to 123. Instead, the test fails because AutoFixture seeds `TicketNo` with a random integer.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!

```
    private Locate Build(Func<IPostprocessComposer<Locate>, IPostprocessComposer<Locate>> action)
    {
        var customizationComposer = _fixture.Build<Locate>();
        var postProcessComposer = customizationComposer
            .With(x => x.TicketNo, DateTime.Now.ToFileTime())
            .With(x => x.On1CallNotified, false)
            .Without(x => x.Attachments)
            .Without(x => x.Comments)
            .Without(x => x.Reviews)
            .Without(x => x.ScheduledCrew)
            .Without(x => x.PendingDecision)
            .Without(x => x.FinalDecision)
            .Without(x => x.ConflictResolution);

        postProcessComposer = action(postProcessComposer);

        return postProcessComposer.Create();
    }
```